# Can't login to coreOS after PXE deployment

Tags: pxe-boot, coreos

I'm trying to deploy CoreOS using Ubuntu PXE server. The target boots, loads CoreOS and asks for username and password. That's where I'm stuck.

I've set up Apache on Ubuntu and I can access files I put in apache html directory from my target, so, Apache works fine. The relevant line in default file looks like:

append coreos.config.url=http://[IP ADDRESS]/pxe-config.yaml

pxe-config.yaml looks like:

## cloud-config

#
users:
    - name: "core"
      groups:
      - "sudo"
      ssh-authorized-keys"
      - "*SSH KEY*"

When I try to connect to the target using ssh, it keeps asking for password although I've specified the key without passphrase.
I'm not even sure that the config file is accessed and read.

Is there a way to check it without logging in? What can be my problem with login?

Answer (score 0):

See how Serva does to PXE boot CoreOS [here](https://www.vercot.com/~serva/an/NonWindowsPXE3.html).
It seems in your case you forgot to append the `coreos.autologin` parameter.

From Serva website

```
;-Serva v3.0 Non-Windows Asset Information File 
;-Boot/Install:
;  Container Linux - CoreOS 
;-Tested on:
;  coreos_production_iso_image.iso (1576.4.0)
;-Require:
;  \SERVA_REPO\ offered as HTTP root if cloud-config-url is used
;-Notes:
;
[PXESERVA_MENU_ENTRY]
asset    = Container Linux - CoreOS
platform = amd64

kernel_bios    = /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/coreos/vmlinuz
append_bios    = initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/coreos/cpio.gz coreos.autologin
;append_bios    = initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/coreos/cpio.gz cloud-config-url=http://$IP_BSRV$/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/pxe-cloud-config.yml    

kernel_efi64    = /NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/coreos/vmlinuz
append_efi64    = initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/coreos/cpio.gz coreos.autologin
;append_efi64    = initrd=/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/coreos/cpio.gz cloud-config-url=http://$IP_BSRV$/NWA_PXE/$HEAD_DIR$/pxe-cloud-config.yml
```